# Tool tip expanding box

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I set the `width` and `height` to 100% for the tooltip

```
.tool-tip,
.tool-tip.top{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -43px;
}
```

but it still doesn't expand to whatever I put in the content box. Check it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/sTCh4/1/

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

add the div that hold's the `input` and the Tool Tip a `width` for instance of `100%;`

to work on the jsfiddle you provided add to the `<div class="on-focus clearfix" style="position: relative; padding: 0px; float: left; width: 100%;">` 
you`ll have to do some more styling to it in order to make it look good but this will make you tool tip big

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-table`. Then make a few other changes to reposition your css arrow so its not 50% down the side of the expanded box.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/sTCh4/4/)

```
*:not(.on-focus) > .tool-tip.slideIn,
.on-focus > .tool-tip{
    display: inline-table;
}
.tool-tip.right{
    top: 15px;
    right: auto;
    left: 106%;
    margin-top: -12px;
    margin-right: auto; 
    margin-left: auto;
}

.tool-tip.right:after{
    left: -5px;
    top: 11px;  
    margin-top: -6px;
    bottom: auto;
    border-top-color: transparent;  
    border-right-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, .7); 
}
```